# How to bind the selecteditem property of Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.TreeView when Selection mode is Multiple

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, treeview, winui

I am using the Treeview control of Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls with 'multiple' selection mode. Here I need to bind some property as *SelectedItem* in twoway binding to fetch the selected nodes into an enumerable collection.
But Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.TreeView does not have *selectedItem property* or any *selectionChanged event*. How do I fetch the selected nodes?

```
<muxc:TreeView SelectionMode="Multiple" Width="300" x:Name="CategoriesTree" 
              ItemsSource="{x:Bind _vm.Categories, Mode=OneWay}">
      <muxc:TreeView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="local1:CategoriesInfo">
                      <TreeViewItem ItemsSource="{x:Bind SubCategories}" Content="{x:Bind Name}" />
            </DataTemplate>
      </muxc:TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</muxc:TreeView>
```

I tried to use TreeView of Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls in WinUi2 but it throws a runtime error

> No such Interface supported

by Windows.Ui.Xaml. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/winui/api/microsoft.ui.xaml.controls.treeview?view=winui-2.8#events), there is no node selectionChanged event for now.

Even with `TreeView.ItemInvoked` [Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/winui/api/microsoft.ui.xaml.controls.treeview.iteminvoked?view=winui-2.8)

> This event is not fired when the item's multiple-selection checkbox is
> checked or unchecked.

Here is a workaround, you can handle the [mouse click event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.pointerreleased?view=winrt-22621) in the TreeView, detect the change of the TreeView SelectedNodes.

```
int oldCount = 0;

public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    DessertTree.AddHandler(PointerReleasedEvent, new PointerEventHandler(TreeView_OnPointerReleased), true);       
}

private void TreeView_OnPointerReleased(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{

    if (oldCount != DessertTree.SelectedNodes.Count)
    {
        foreach (TreeViewNode node in DessertTree.SelectedNodes)
        {
           do somthing...

        }
        oldCount = DessertTree.SelectedNodes.Count;
    }

}
```